# dojo require function's parameter

Tags: function, dojo, require

Take simple examples as below:

```
require(["dojo/_base/ready", "dojo/_base/declare"], function(ready, declare) {
}
```

How to explain ready and declare to dojo core? Class name?
In another example I often see:

```
require(["js/somemodule.js"], function(someName) {
});
```

Many times I see someName not the same as somemodule(ready, declare are the same as the module name at least), nor was it any identifier I could found in somemodule.js or its base. What's the matter? I guess when the argument in require function should be declared in some where and hold a value.

Answer (score 4):

The variable name `someName` is something you choose yourself. It is in fact the variable referencing to the module. So that means that `someName` refers to the module `js/somemodule.js`.

If you want to call a function of `js/somemodule.js`, you use:

```js
someName.myFunction();
```

Usually people give it the same name as the module (or something similar) because it's easier to remember. But it's not always the case, because if there are dashes in the module name, people usually use camel case, for example:

```js
require(["dojo/dom-construct"], function(domContruct) {
    domConstruct.create(...);
});
```

But the following is also correct (and does exactly the same):

```js
require(["dojo/dom-construct"], function(theAwesomeModule) {
    theAwesomeModule.create(...);
});
```

Not only Dojo uses this, but the AMD loader is a general principle in JavaScript. For example, look at the [AMD info page](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) of Require.js.

Comment: Yep, it's like saying `var a = b;` except it happens as `require(["b"],function(a){});`